# How do I use calc(100%-50px) to minus the pixels from the top?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have two divs , One for my chart legend and one for my chart.
I want to display the legend at the top. My legend is 50px; But when I use height: calc(100%-50px). It minuses the 50 pixels from the bottom. How do I minus the 50 pixels from the top and put my legend div there instead? I don't mind a solution which uses Javascript or even D3. A pure CSS solution would be nice.

```css
.treemap-chart-container .treemap-chart {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  float: left;
}

.legend {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="treemap-chart-container">
  <div class="treemap-chart"></div>
  <div class="legend" id="legendContainer"></div>
</div>
```

BTW , I realize that the positioning of the div elements affect it as well. If for example , the legend div render 1st,then it will appear at the top. But in my case the chart div is 1st. So how to exchange the positions of the two divs?

Comment: try `.treemap-chart-container { display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; }`

Comment: Thank you. Would you like to put that as your answer? I would mark it as correct. And also I have legend position configuration. So how do I reset it back to the bottom if it is set to bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place it on top by

```
.treemap-chart-container { display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; }
```

Then you may place it on bottom again

```
.treemap-chart-container { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

Comment: flex-direction: column does not seem to be working. flex-direction is a style right? Not an attribute?

Comment: I think its because I need to minus the pixels back at the bottom ? because from what I see the top still has space after I changed flex-direction to column

Comment: @SyedAriff or you can just use `.treemap-chart-container { display: block; }` to put it in the bottom again

Comment: display : block just takes the whole legend div out of the view.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to do like this?

```css
.container{
   height:100vh;
   background:lightblue;
}

.legend{
   height:50px;
   background:red;
}

.chart{
   height:calc(100% - 50px);
   background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="legend">legend 50px</div>
   <div class="chart">chart calc(100% - 50px);</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `.treemap-chart` to be a full-page element with the label sitting at top, you really do simply want to subtract `50px` from the `height` of `.treemap-chart`. Because the elements will sit on top of one another, the chart will be offset by `50px`, thus taking up all remaining room with `100vh`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.treemap-chart-container .treemap-chart {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  float: left;
}

.legend {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: left;
}

/* Added to show in example */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Added to show in example */
.legend {
  background: blue;
}

/* Added to show in example */
.treemap-chart-container {
  height: 100vh;
}

/* Added to show in example */
.treemap-chart {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="legend">Legend</div>
<div class="treemap-chart-container">
  <div class="treemap-chart">
    Chart
  </div>
</div>
```

**However**, if `.legend` has absolute positioning (based on your framework), you may be looking for `margin-top` on the chart to specify the offset. In this case, ironically, you don't actually need `calc()` at **all** for this; just leave the `height` as the height you want, and set `margin-top` to `50px`:

```css
.treemap-chart-container .treemap-chart {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.legend {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Added to show in example */

body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Added to show in example */

.legend {
  background: blue;
}


/* Added to show in example */

.treemap-chart-container {
  height: 100vh;
}


/* Added to show in example */

.treemap-chart {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="legend">Legend</div>
<div class="treemap-chart-container">
  <div class="treemap-chart">
    Chart
  </div>
</div>
```